# When did Captain America start to fight super villains?

Tags: marvel

Due to setup of Captain America, it feels like he was designed to fight against ordinary Earth crimes and underworld.

When did he first face a super villain or an alien threat? Was it the first comic? Or, later?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Red Skull](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_Skull) appeared in the very first Captain America comic (*Captain America #1*) in 1941. You can't get any earlier than that. Captain America also fought other super-powered enemies, such as [Namor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Namor) and [Baron Zemo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baron_Heinrich_Zemo#Baron_Heinrich_Zemo).